# basicLocaleListResolution’ is imported from both error

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been getting an error like this for a few days now and couldn't find a solution. I did flutter clean and flutter run but no change

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.5.5/lib/src/state/store.dart:74:31: Error: ‘basicLocaleListResolution’ is imported from both ‘package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart’ and ‘package:device_preview/src/locales/locales.dart’.
final defaultLocale = basicLocaleListResolution(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script ‘C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle’ line: 1005

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ‘:app:compileFlutterBuildDebug’.

Process ’command ‘C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat’' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Try:
Run with –stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with –info or –debug option to get more log output. Run with –scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 2):

You have two class with same name. if you want use both of them. after one of imports write  `as [name]`. for example

import 'package:flutter/adir/a.dart';
import 'package:flutter/bdir/a.dart' as newA;

and when want use it. first write custom name then write class name:

final List<newA.a> ex=[];